# how to iterate over two lists in batch processing

Tags: windows, batch-file

I would like to run a console app from a batch file. actually, the console app is run from another batch file. The app can take two command line parameters, a and b. They are file names. I have two lists of files, alist.txt and blist.txt, which are the same length. I would like, if possible to run the batch like this:

```
FOR /F %%a in (alist.txt)  %%b in (blist.txt) do runconsolebatch.bat %%a %%b
```

but that doesn't work. When I run it I get "%b was unexpected at this time."

If I somehow nest them, that wouldn't work. I could join the two file lists into one file...like this?

```
  file1A    file2A

  file1B    file2B
```

but I'm not sure how I could assign file1A to %a and file1B to %b, or if that's possible.

4/12/2015: I thought this was solved. I even used what I *thought* was the correct batch file but it doesn't work. What I get now is the first output line is correct and the rest like this:

The first line works correctly. BUT I only get two more lines even though the DIR.TXT file has 5 entries and the NAMES.TXT file has 3 ENTRIES. That should be 15 lines of output. The rest of the output is this:

```
G:\test>(
set /p "valueA="  
 runconsolebatch.bat !valueA! name1.txt 
)  

Command line: in=!valueA! name1.txt 

failure validating G:\test\source\!VALUEA!: file may not be correctly specified or doesn't exist.
```

This is the batch file I'm using:

```
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
    <"dir2.txt" (
        for /f "usebackq delims=" %%b in ("names.txt") do (
            set /p "valueA="
            runconsolebatch.bat !valueA! %%b
        )
    )
```

And if I change runconsolebatch.bat to echo so I get

```
echo !valueA!  %%b
```

I get three lines of output: the first line from dir2.txt and the first line from names.txt, second and second and third and third.

FOR SOME REASON, while this worked at one time, it doesn't now. Here's my batch file:

```
@echo off
setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
<"blist.txt" (
    for /f "usebackq delims=" %%b in ("alist.txt") do (
        set /p "valueA="
        echo !valueA! %%b
    )
)
```

blist.txt is

```
1111
2222
3333
4444
```

and alist.txt is

```
AAAA
BBBB
CCCC
```

but the output of the batch file is:

```
1111 AAAA
2222 BBBB
3333 CCCC
```

when it should be

```
1111 AAAA
1111 BBBB
```

etc.

Doubtless it's a silly typo but...what? Also this is just run in a regular user command shell.

Comment: Just to clarify, if both files have, say, 10 files each, then you want to run the app 10 times? Not 10x10=100 or something?

Comment: yes, run the app 10 times. I want to run the app against a variety of files, the actual lists will have about 1000 lines if I can do this.

Comment: You will not get 15 lines. Both files are being readed in parallel (as indicated in the question), and the control of how many lines are readed is in the `for`, so, if the `names.txt` file has three lines, you will get three lines. Also, if from a batch file you want to call another batch file and that the execution flow returns to the caller, you will need to use `call runconsolebatch.bat .....`, else the execution flow is transfered and does not return to the caller.

Comment: So how do I get 15 lines? I changed to call run.... but that alone didn't work.

Comment: Getting the 15 lines (read all the lines in one file for any of the lines in the other) has no relation to the original question (read a line from one file for one line in the other). You need two nested `for` loops, but this is out of the scope of this question. Please, start a new question so we can help.

Comment: Yes, I would start a new question but I solved it thanks to the input I got here. Here's my solution and I checked and it works:

@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
    for /f "usebackq delims=" %%a in ("dir.txt") do (
             
         for /f "usebackq delims=" %%b in ("names.txt") do (
              
             echo %%b %%a
        )
    )

Answer (score 5):

Read the `Blist.txt` with a `for` loop and `AList.txt` with a file input redirection and `set /p` command.

```
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
    <"Alist.txt" (
        for /f "usebackq delims=" %%b in ("Blist.txt") do (
            set /p "valueA="
            echo !valueA! %%b
        )
    )
```

For values as the indicated in the question this should work. Problematic characters or lines longer than 1021 characters should need aditional code.

Comment: clever to combine set/p and for/f.+1

Comment: Please see my additional comment above. For some reason it does not work. (Windows 10 Enterprise command shell).

Comment: @Ron, I think you are mixing cases. The code in the answer reads two files in parallel (the original question), but you now need a nested read, something the answer is not addressing. You can just simply use two anidated `for /f` loops as you already point in your last comment under the question.

Comment: You (@MC ND) are correct. I used two for loops and it worked perfectly. Not sure why I thought the other way worked. But thanks!!!